# Making REF field always visible in MS Word 2010

Tags: text, ms-word, header, field, hidden

I have REF fields in my headers and footers. They reference *bookmarked* text form fields in the main body of the document because you can't put text form fields in headers or footers. They look like this:

{ REF my_bookmark_1 }

If Show/Hide is set to Hide, I can't see the resolved contents of the REF fields.
If I set my Word options to always show and always print hidden text I can see them, but not everyone has these options set.

Is there a way to make the REF fields visible all the time?

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

Do the formfields which these REF fields reference have the 'calculate on exit' property set? If so, their content should always be in synch. Beyond that, whether your users will see where the empty REF fields are depends on how they have Word configured; it is out of your control.

Comment: Thanks @macropod. Maybe I'll just do a search and replace within all the headers and footers instead.